# Keep window dialog when mouseover to it, else

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a dialog box that appears on the **top** **left** of my current position. 
If I scroll my mouse into the dialog box, it should remain there and if I scroll my mouse out of the dialog box, the popup window should disappear. This works well when I add the mouseover event to the dialog box.

However, If I move my mouse away and have never entered the dialog box, I also hope that the dialog box should disappear. I wonder what should I do to make this happened?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Consider listening for mouse move, and compare those to the location/size of the dialog box manually.